# Изображение рядом с Button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня есть кнопка, мне нужно что бы при нажатии на нее изображение с кнопками появлялось под кнопкой. Все кнопки генерируются программно. На картинке 1 будут находится еще кнопки. Пробовал сделать через диалоговое окно, но оно выдает изображение всегда в центре. Подскажите как привязать данное изображение к позиции кнопки что бы оно выводилось под ней как показано на картинке 2?

[image: картинка 1]

[image: картинка 2]

Comment: Используйте Popup menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так:

```
public void showPopup(View at){
    View popupView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);  
    popupView.findViewBydId(R.id.minutes_5).setOnClickListener(v->{...});
    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);
    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(at, xoff, yoff); // с офсетами поиграйте чтоб спозиционировать относительно кнопки
                                                // 0,0 - левый нижний угол кнопки (почти всегда) 
}
```

- `at` - ваша кнопка, на которую жмете
- `R.layout.popup_window` - ваш layout с минутами.